# Get items in specific index list of lists

Tags: list, tcl

I have a key-value list such as:

```
set x {{a 1} {b 2} {c 3}}
```

I need to extract all the items in index=1 in all sub-lists to get:

```
{1 2 3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to conscript the `dict values` command:

```
dict values [concat {*}{{a 1} {b 2} {c 3}}]
```

How this works: the `dict values` collects a list consisting of every other item (starting from the second) in another list. This is intended to be used on dictionaries, but since dictionaries are basically just even-sized lists, it works on any even-sized list, with one caveat: if any key appears more than once, the result of `dict values` will only contain the last value associated with that key.

A list consisting of two-item sublists can easily be transformed into an even-sized list by passing the sublists individually as arguments to `concat`.

Another way is to traverse the list using one of the methods mentioned in the other answers, or maybe like this:

```
set res {}
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $x]} {incr i} {
    lappend res [lindex $x $i 1]
}
set res
```

This is similar to

```
set res {}
foreach item $x {
    lappend res [lindex $item 1]
}
set res
```

(or the corresponding `lmap item $x {lindex $item 1}`)

but does provide the option to 1) start at an index ≠ 0, 2) end before the end of the list, and 3) traverse the list by two (or more) item steps.

Documentation: [concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: One thing to be careful about: if one of the pairs has the same 0th element, you'll lose one of the values: `dict values [concat {*}{{a 1} {b 2} {c 3} {a 4}}]` returns `4 2 3`

Comment: @glennjackman: yep, hence my footnote. But maybe I ought make that more clear.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
$ set y {}
$ foreach sublist $x { lappend y  [lindex $sublist 1]}
$ puts $y
1 2 3
```

**A solution for TCL  8.6 or newer**:

Use `lmap` to iterate through `x` without saving value anywhere ,in one-line:

```
$ lmap sublist $x {lindex $sublist 1}
```

References:
[lmap,tcl.tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/13920)

Comment: @HardwareEng. I added a one-line solution using `lmap`

Comment: Good one. But unfortunately, I'm using Tcl8.5

Comment: The minimal 8.6 version (without saving the value anywhere) is `lmap sublist $x {lindex $sublist 1}`

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following function:

```
proc MapList {Var List Script} {
    if {![llength $List]} {return $List}
    upvar 1 $Var Item
    foreach Item $List {lappend Res [uplevel 1 $Script]}
    return $Res
}
```

And used it like this:

```
MapList Arg $x {lindex $Arg 1}
```