# Sum of elements/numbers in N lists in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

How to add elements/numbers from n lists in tcl ?
I have tried in python and it worked using below:

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(*C)]
```

How to do this in tcl?
Is there a zip function in tcl?

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

I have 2 lists for now:

```
l1 {11 333 4 567 129}
l2 {23 47 56 10 13}
```

I can have N-number of lists

I need to return element wise sum from these lists.

for two lists I implemented below :

```
set result {}
foreach x $l1 y $l2 {
    lappend result [expr {$x + $y}]
}
```

My concern is: I can have one or many lists. So in that scenario how do I implement?

Comment: How are your N lists represented?

Comment: Example
list1 {1,2,33,444,5}
list2 {22,34,5555,34334}

# of lists can be 1 or many , all elements inside the list are numbers

Comment: You should put that in your question, along with expected results. One sum per list? One total sum of both lists? (And tcl lists aren't separated by commas... Please include valid tcl, not pseudocode)

Comment: Tcl doesn't have `zip` built in (you can build it of course) but instead has a rich set of options for multi-list iteration with `foreach` and `lmap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a new list of the pairwise sums of the elements of two lists:

```
set result [lmap a $list1 b $list2 { expr {$a + $b} }]
```

Make the obvious addition for three lists, four lists, etc.

Comment: what if I have say 10-15 lists?
I want to use less variables

Comment: Then you don't want a variable per list, you want something else like a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

There are no function similar to `zip` in Tcl as far as I'm aware. You can however create one if you want to. A rough one might be like this:

```
proc zip {lists} {
    set result {}

    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength [lindex $lists 0]]} {incr i} {
        set elem {}
        foreach list $lists {
            if {$i >= [llength $list]} {return $result}
            lappend elem [lindex $list $i]
        }
        lappend result $elem
    }
    return $result
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
set l1 {11 333 4 567 129}
set l2 {23 47 56 10 13}

set ln [list $l1 $l2]

set sum [lmap x [zip $ln] {::tcl::mathop::+ {*}$x}]
# 34 380 60 577 142
```

Answer (score 0):

> Then you don't want a variable per list, you want something else like a list of lists.

This is my take on the above recommendation by Shawn:

```
set l1 {11 333 4 567 129}
set l2 {23 47 56 10 13}

lappend l $l1 $l2

proc zippedSum {p} {
    set inner [llength [lindex $p 0]]
    set result [list]
    for {set i 0} {$i < $inner} {incr i} {
       lappend result [::tcl::mathop::+ {*}[lmap sublist $p {lindex $sublist $i}]]
    }
    return $result
}

zippedSum $l
```

You would not maintain separate variables, but a list of lists (`l`). Then you would process the sublists per index (with the maximum index determined by the first sublist), using the [lmap/lindex combo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482086/get-items-in-specific-index-list-of-lists) recommended elsewhere for what you call zipping.

Comment: An alternative to lmap/lindex, but less performant, is using `lsearch -all -inline -index $i -subindices -integer $p *`.